# Insert or replace like operation for Pandas HDFStore (table)

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to perform an "Insert or Replace" like operation on a pandas hdf store (table format). Is there an efficient way of doing this? I'm only considering matching on the index.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#delete-from-a-table)? Mixing that with appends may work, but I'm not sure how great performance will be. Does the order on disk matter?

Comment: @TomAugspurger Thanks for the pointer! After reading your link I'm thinking that it may be better to store the actual data in a database and load relevant portions into Pandas. The more I look into it the more it seems Pandas is not that great with data that keeps changing but is awesome with static data. Is that correct?

Comment: @KaushikGhose ``Pytables`` can store changing data. But it is MUCH better to store as appends. Think of HDF5 as a database that is great at queries. It is optimized for speed not ACID. If your data is changing a lot but needs a backing store, then a sql style db can complement the static/appendable data heavy portion that HDF5 stores.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks! In my use case I have a bunch of raw data files (sessions) that I ETL into a larger store. Pandas + Pytables does great, except when I have to go back to a previous session and reprocess it for some reason. In such a case I can not append but must first destroy the old entries. I found that tricky with Pandas. Also, I ran into some grief when I tried concurrent reads with an HDF5 store which I think is not an issue with sqlite

Comment: concurrent reading is OK; but make sure that you are NOT writing at the same time. I do what you are describing all the time. I will simply rewrite the files (just read them in chunks, replace as needed, write as chunks). Your data flow is much more efficient to create essentially 'read-only' data for the most part.

Comment: @Jeff Hmm, I had a funky problem with concurrent reads on an hdf5 file that I created with h5py (No writes). I was using Multiprocessing and ran into an intermittent problem where I would occasionally read garbage data. I had this regardless of whether I used a global file pointer or opened the file afresh in each thread. I had a devil of a time replicating the problem because it was so intermittent. Have you ever run into this?

Comment: you need to open it in each process separately. should be read threadsafe.